# Query working on second attempt but not first

Tags: php, mysql

I want to track when users last logged in, so i have added a column in my database that is time stamped and can be updated every time they log in, and added an update into the login function, but when i login i get an error saying 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' and nothing happens to my database, but if i click login again it logs me in fine and updates the table as i wanted. 
Here is my login function:

```
public function login($email,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM po_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id ");
        $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
            {
                if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                {

                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE po_users SET lastLogIn = current_timestamp WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
                    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
                    $userRow=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    return true;
                }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: betting the session is only kicking in after it's been set

Comment: Any suggestions on how to set it and then update it?

Comment: check if the session is set first, then run the query - `if/else`

Comment: Im still struggling, i think i am over thinking it, could you give me an example with some code? would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't use "fetchAll" after an update... So try this instead:

```
public function login($email,$upass) {
    try {
        $select_user_stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM po_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id ");
        $select_user_stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
        $userRow = $select_user_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($select_user_stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y") {
                if($userRow['userPass'] == md5($upass)) {
                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                    $update_user_stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE po_users SET lastLogIn = current_timestamp WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
                    $update_user_stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
                    $select_user_stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email)); // do a search again here...
                    $userRow = $select_user_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    return true;
                }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, as I thought I was over thinking it, and had nested it inside another unnecessary if statement.